# Game Center Invitation Handler for when someone accepts and invite in cocos2D

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, game-center, invite

I have it working where if two players are in the same scene you can invite them and it'll add them to the players list when they accept.

What I don't have working and I'm not sure how to do is make the right scene load up when one player isn't in the app and the other player is in the app sending an invite request from one of the `CCScene`s.

I don't know if there is a way to do this or if it's the best way. My thoughts on this is that I want to send the name of the scene the person inviting a player is in to the person they are inviting through the invite handler. I'd assume I would have to send info somehow to the application `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` if they weren't in the app but if they were I'd have it handler that elsewhere. I've been searching everywhere and haven't come across anything. If you guys know how do this or a better way of doing it I would be greatly appreciative for your help.

Here is the code I use for the invite handler:

```
[GKMatchmaker sharedMatchmaker].inviteHandler = ^(GKInvite *acceptedInvite, NSArray *playersToInvite) {
    UIViewController *topLevelViewController = self.presentingViewController;
    bool isInviter = NO;

    if (acceptedInvite) {
        isInviter = NO;
        GKMatchmakerViewController *mmvc = [[[GKMatchmakerViewController alloc] initWithInvite:acceptedInvite] autorelease];
        mmvc.matchmakerDelegate = self;

        if ([topLevelViewController modalViewController] != nil)
            [topLevelViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];

        [topLevelViewController presentModalViewController:mmvc animated:YES];
    } else if (playersToInvite) {
        isInviter = NO;
        GKMatchRequest *request = [[[GKMatchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
        request.minPlayers = 2;
        request.maxPlayers = 2;
        request.playersToInvite = playersToInvite;

        GKMatchmakerViewController *mmvc = [[[GKMatchmakerViewController alloc] initWithMatchRequest:request] autorelease];
        mmvc.matchmakerDelegate = self;

        if ([topLevelViewController modalViewController] != nil)
            [topLevelViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];

        [topLevelViewController presentModalViewController:mmvc animated:YES];
    }
};
```